# How to map a plotting function with multiple arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have a large dataset and I am trying to plot  multiple graphs using  a function. Now the function is supposed to loop and plot charts per hospital and also facet by birth weight group.

Here is how the code for the function looks like

```
myplott <- function(actual_data, hospital, weightsgrp) {
  
  print(paste0("Plot for hospital: ", hospital))
  
  p <- ggplot(actual_data %>% filter(hosp_id == hospital , weight.group == weightsgrp), 
              aes(x = format(date_discharge,"%b"), y = as.numeric(mortality), 
                  group = weightsgrp)) +
    facet_wrap(~weight.group) +
    geom_bar( stat = "identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylab("Percentage %") +
    ggtitle(hospital) +
    
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, hjust = 1, angle = 45)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20), legend.position = "top") +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  
  return(p)
  
  print(p)
  
}
```

Now this function works well. I am able to even see one plot using

```
myplott(actual_data, "hospital name", "weight group")
```

Now here is my problem.

When I try to map that plotting function so that to generate a plot list for multiple hospitals, I get an error. Here is how I map the function

```
plot_list <- unique(actual_data$hosp_id) %>% 
  purrr::set_names() %>% 
  purrr::map( ~ myplott(actual_data, .x))
```

And this is the error I get

```
[1] "Plot for hospital: Bung Hospital"
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..2 = weight.group == weightsgrp`.
i The error occurred in group 1: hosp_id = "Bung Hospital", weight.group = "1000 gms & Below".
Caused by error:
! argument "weightsgrp" is missing, with no default
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In map your are only passing the dataset `actual_data` and the `hospital`but the weightsgrp is missing. Perhaps you want `myplott(actual_data, .x, "weight group")`?

Comment: Yeah, it only looks like you've passed two arguments to `myplott`. What is the output of `unique(actual_data$hosp_id) %>% purrr::set_names()`?